# Help with measure theory problem ? (completion of measure )

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure and let $\mu^{\ast}$ be the outer measure induced by $\mu$. $M^{\ast}$ is the sigma algebra of $m^{\ast}$ measurable sets, and define $\overline{\mu}:=\mu^{\ast}|_{\cal M^{\ast}}$.

If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, prove $\overline{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$.

I get stuck in this one in 2 days. Please help.

Note : I think I should prove $\overline{M} = M^{\ast}$ . And I have completed the proof. However, what I don't understand is the relationship between $\overline{\mu}$ , $\mu$ and $\mu^{\ast}$. I know  $\overline{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$ for $\overline{M}$.

Comment: Please, finish typing the dollar signs so the $\LaTeX$ renders!

Comment: Thanks for help editing. I am new in using Latex format.

Answer (score 1):

$\mu^*$ is defined on all subsets of $X$, and is just an outer measure. $\bar{\mu}$ is a measure defined on the sigma algebra of $\mu^*$ measurable subsets of $X$, $M^*$. $\mu$ is a measure defined on the sets in the sigma algebra $M$ only.

The three agree wherever they are all defined.

Comment: Thank you, can you please point out how μ¯ is the completion of μ when $\overline{M} = M^{\ast}$ ?